# Macron accent above some Cyrillic letters is shifted

Tags: cyrillic, japanese, luatexja, macron

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{EB Garamond}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize = 14}

\begin{document}

ш\={ю}кан

\end{document}
```

It's supposed to produce a macron accent above ю, but you can see below that the bar is above the space between ю and к.

[image]

## Update

Solution

```
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{ю}{\accent"0304 ю}
```

doesn't work very well. It creates a strange conflict between `tabular`, `luatexja` and `xcolor`. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage[haranoaji]{luatexja-preset}

\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange = {-2, -3}}

\setotherlanguages{english, russian}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{EB Garamond}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{ю}{\accent"0304 ю}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth} l}
    習慣&ш\=юкан\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following error:

```
luatexja/ltj-jfmglue.lua:647: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (local 'c')
```

Removing either of the following makes it compile:

- `\=` from `ш\=юкан`
- `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{ю}{\accent"0304 ю}`
- `table` from `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

## Update 2

I consider the conflict with `luatexja` a bug in `luatexja`. I hope they will fix it. Cyrillic is irrelevant for this conflict. `luatexja` just doesn't like `\accent`

## Update 3

Here is a workaround that silences `luatexja`:

```
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{Ю}{\hspace*{0pt}\accent"0304 Ю}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{ю}{\hspace*{0pt}\accent"0304 ю}
```

## Update 4

`luatexja` developers are amazing. They fixed the bug within an hour after I filed it.

Comment: Possibly `\hspace*{0pt}` or you could have line breaks in front of the accented characters.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenType fonts require *very* patient work for supporting combining characters, that's a fact, and similar problems are, unfortunately, common.

Apparently, the font developer here forgot to add proper anchor points for combining characters in some slots of the font.

Also я Е О Э Ю Я suffer from the same problem. However, this can be cured by using the legacy method for accents.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{EB Garamond}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{ю}{\accent"0304 ю}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{я}{\accent"0304 я}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{Е}{\accent"0304 Е}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{О}{\accent"0304 О}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{Э}{\accent"0304 Э}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{Ю}{\accent"0304 Ю}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{Я}{\accent"0304 Я}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize = 14}

\begin{document}

ш\={ю}кан

\=а\=е\=и\=о\=у\=э\=ю\=я

\=A\=Е\=И\=О\=У\=Э\=Ю\=Я

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the record, here's the output with the seven `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand` lines omitted.

[image]

Comment: I wonder how to get attention of EB Garamond developer?

Comment: @facetus https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12

Comment: It doesn't seem there is any activity recently in fixing issues on GitHub.

Comment: `DeclareTextCompositeCommand` conflicts with a combination of `tabular`, `xcolor` and `luatexja`. See the updated question.

Comment: Is there a reason to use code point 0x304? I tried 0xAF, it seems like it works just the same.

Comment: @facetus No specific reason, actually

Answer (score 1):

To answer your follow-up question, you can use `babel` to get automatic language detection, rather than `luatexja`.  It doesn’t necessarily support every `luatexja` and `polyglossia` feature you might be using, but it should work for you, and it fixes this bug.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{japanese}
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=ids fonts]{russian}

\defaultfontfeatures[HaranoAjiMincho]{
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,
  Scale=MatchUppercase
}

\babelfont{rm}{EBGaramond}
\babelfont[japanese]{rm}{HaranoAjiMincho}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{ю}{\accent"0304 ю}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} l}
    習慣&ш\=юкан\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond / Harano Aji Mincho sample]

Comment: Thanks. I think it's always possible to get rid of a problem by reducing the functionality. We have a joke in Russia: the best remedy for a headache is the guillotine. But wouldn't it be wonderful to have everything?

Comment: @facetus There probably is a `babel` equivalent for whatever it is you wanted to do with the other packages, though.

Comment: Like tate text direction for Japanese? `babel` "does not care about any Japanese typesetting requirements". Source: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/japanese/japanese.pdf

Comment: @facetus There technically is support for rotated glyphs for vertical writing in `fontspec`, but only in XeLaTeX and only if you place them in a `rotatebox` yourself. So, in practical terms, good example, that’s unsupported.

Comment: Please, refer to the document I posted above for other typesetting differences of Japanese text.

Comment: @facetus `babel` probably suffices, then, to insert words and short phrases in Japanese, written left-to-right, in a multi-lingual document.

Comment: This discussion is taking a counterproductive turn. Can you just believe me and free me of the burden to prove to you that I need `luatexja`?

Comment: @facetus Oh, sorry, I didn’t think we were arguing. Like I said in my answer originally, `babel` does not support all the features of `lualatexja`, and again, vertical writing was a good example.

Comment: @facetus I wouldn't say babel “does not care about ANY Japanese typesetting requirements”. It does line breaking, for example. See https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/samples/hungarian-japanese.pdf . (Of course, this doesn't mean you can or must get rid of `luatexja`.)

Comment: @JavierBezos I just quoted a document from "Japanese TeX Development Community". If they are wrong, I would send them an email. Here is the source I quoted: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/japanese/japanese.pdf. There is an email in the document.